# Debian Software Raid1 boot failure after trying to change one disk

Tags: debian, raid1, grub

I have a server running Debian 11 with 3 HDDs, each 500gb using software RAID1.

I'm now in the process of upgrading so I have 2x1TB drives. To accomplish this I followed [this guide](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Growing#Expanding_existing_partitions).

The disk I removed first was `/dev/sda`. Now when I have 2 disks left in the server it cannot boot. BIOS says it cannot find a system disk with OS.

I managed to do research and my guess is that the bootloader is not available on my other 2 disks (`/dev/sdb /dev/sdc)`. Using SuperGrub2Disk I can boot to my system! I figured all I had to do was `grub-install /dev/sda` which is now my first disk. However it did not solve anything, I'm still unable to boot without SuperGrub2Disk.

I need help with guiding me in the right direction of what else to check, or if I tried installing grub to my disk incorrectly somehow.

Extremely grateful for any help! I'm still a amateur debian user.

What info from the terminal would you like to have?

Result of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG HD502HJ
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe9299246

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 976771071 976769024 465.8G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sdb: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA DT01ACA0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x61294bfb

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 976771071 976769024 465.8G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sdc: 28.65 GiB, 30765219840 bytes, 60088320 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Blade
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0a885191

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 60088319 60086272 28.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Disk /dev/md0: 465.63 GiB, 499970473984 bytes, 976504832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa127a3b1

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/md0p1  *           2 974503919 974503918 464.7G 83 Linux
/dev/md0p2      974503920 976504649   2000730 976.9M  5 Extended
/dev/md0p5      974503922 976504649   2000728 976.9M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: Check from what disk bios boot is configured. Install grub on all disks. Boot you system and update grub configuration update-grub

Comment: I have tried all this and it still won't give me any success

Comment: How exactly did you install the bootloader? (Please, put exact commands and the output.)